# Is it possible to create an easy to use encryption/decryption method that will never be comprimised?

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design

In the comments of the question "[Why programming languages don't provide simple encryption methods?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1563/why-programming-languages-dont-provide-simple-encryption-methods)" the following statement was made:

> A well thought out, tested and understood standard that has undergone
>   extensive review by the crypto community has a much better [chance] of
>   avoiding compromise than a system designed by a single engineer using
>   a fairly low level library.

to me such a system would have the following requirements:

- Encryption would require nothing more than a string of text to encrypt and an easily programmatic producible "key".
- Decryption would require nothing more than an easily programmatic producible "key".
- The result would not ever be able to be determined with out access to the key even given a reasonably huge finite (IE more than we can ever expect to have available) amount of computing power.
- No method of attack would ever trivialize the determining the key or the source text used for the encryption.

My opinion is that the nature of encryption is that it is impossible for a standard like this to work given an infinite amount of computing power. We may be able to do this for the computing power of today but eventually given enough power it will be trivial to decrypt any scheme if we know how the scheme works and it only requires a single key. Is such a scheme possible?

Comment: I agree with your analysis that given infinite computational resources such a scheme, outside of a OTP, would likely be compromised. Generally success of a crypto-system is defined by showing that the best possible attack is brute forcing the key-space.

I think the more interesting question is if such a scheme is possible given key-space bounded compute time (a more typical definition of security). The most interesting question, to me, is how can we increase our trust in crypto-systems given that non-cryptographically trained engineers will be (mis)using them (fool proof security).

Comment: @EthanHeilman - The problem is computing power is continually increasing and new processor types like GPU's create new functionality that basically trivializes some encryption cracking. So any standard and secure encryption that could be built in would need to be able to withstand brute force.

Comment: I think we can set the bar pretty high in terms of brute force. No one is concerned that AES will be broken due to brute forcing the key. In fact it is quite easy to create a crypto-system with a key so large a computer the size of the universe couldn't brute force it. For instance using all the atoms in the universe ($10^82$ atoms) as computers capable of computing 1 trillion keys a second, one could brute force roughly 2^314 keys a second. To brute force a 512-bit key would take roughly $10^{52}$ years (far far longer than the lifetime of the universe).

Comment: @EthanHeilman - I am confused you indicated that the Rijndael was too complex to be considered simple in the other thread.

Comment: I have no problem with Rijndael (AES) per se, what I have a problem with is that the library is expecting the engineer to turn a secure block-cipher (AES) into a secure crypto-system (AES is fine but it needs all the other stuff: padding, authentication, IV generation, a chaining mode). The default crypto libraries that an engineer encounters should operate at the level of crypto-systems not at the level of primitives. For example bcrypt does a decent job of this with hashing passwords (with some reservations). The default interface is  BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt).

Comment: @EthanHeilman: Deterministic crypto primitives can be implemented as system-independent libraries which can operate without side-effects.  IV generation, however, cannot.  Password salt generation doesn't need a good source of entropy if it has any combination of factors available which would be unlikely to match perfectly in realistic scenarios involving two coincidentally-identical passwords, since the existence of matching password hashes would only benefit someone who knew about the match and *also* knew one of the passwords.  IV generation, however, is much more critical, since...

Comment: ...the discovery of two messages with the same IV would give an attacker a huge amount of information about both messages, even if the attacker initially knew nothing about either.

Answer (score 11):

**If** the key is:

- generated with an unpredictable truly random uniform generator (*not* a pseudo-random generator);
- as long as the data to encrypt;
- used for only one message ever;

**then** this is the [One-Time Pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) model, and you can encrypt data by a simple bitwise XOR (no need for an explicit function, just XOR).

**Otherwise**, there is no solution which resists attackers with infinite computational abilities. Shannon's thesis is all about that.

Comment: Basically, if there is sufficient information in the ciphertext, then an attacker can break it. If there is insufficient information, then no. For example, I picked a number from 1 to 10 and encrypted it by adding a key (from 0 to 100) to it. I got 41. You have infinite computing power. What number did I pick?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Maybe not but I know your key was between 0 and 41... and I know that the encrypted number was <= 42. I have reduced the pool of potentials by ~59%

Comment: Two words: Vernam Cipher

Answer (score 3):

> Is such a scheme possible?

Theoretically "Yes", but only under a certain, single condition...

It is a common misconception that every encryption method can be broken. In connection with his WWII work at Bell Labs, Claude Shannon proved that the one-time pad cipher is unbreakable, provided the key material is

1. truly random,
2. never reused,
3. kept secret from all possible attackers,
4. and of equal or greater length than the message.

Most ciphers, apart from the *"one-time-pad"*, can be broken with enough computational effort by brute force attack, but the amount of effort needed may be exponentially dependent on the key size, as compared to the effort needed to make use of the cipher.

In such cases, effective security could be achieved if it is proven that the effort required (example: the "work factor", as Claude Shannon defines it) is beyond the ability of any adversary. This means it must be shown that no efficient method (as opposed to the time-consuming brute force method) can be found to break the cipher.

As no such proof has been found to date related to a *"one-time-pad"*, the *"one-time-pad"* remains the only **theoretically** unbreakable cipher.

Read again: ...**theoretically** unbreakable...

**UPDATE**

As this came up in the comments... when it comes to creating a one-time pad, there are several hardware solutions and software implementations that would satisfy the "truly random one-time pad" definition. Some initial info can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad#True_randomness , but if you really want to dive into this a bit more, you'll probably want to check on "Randomness Recommendations for Security", which is available at http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1750.txt

Oh, and while I'm updating my answer: the (as OP calls it) *"scheme"* we're talking about is commonly known as **Vernam Cipher**, just in case you want to cross-check my answer using search engines. ;)

RC4 is an example of a Vernam cipher that is widely used on the Internet.

More information about the Vernam Cipher, it's history, it's inventor and related patents can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert_Vernam

Comment: Actually, there's an infinite set of ciphers that are cannot be broken, but they all share the 4 points you list. Trivially, for any bijective function _f_, `f(OTP(x))` is such a cipher.

Comment: I agree with your answer but am not able to accept it because we do not have a method to generate a true random one time pad in a computer program.

Comment: @Chad : to accept an answer, you need to click the "checkmark" next to the answer. ;)

Comment: @e-sushi I know how to accept it.  I am saying that this does not really meet the criteria since we can not programmatically generate a truly random one time pad.

Comment: @Chad : of course you can. But you're correct that "ye average programming language" will not satisfy as they mostly use pseudo-randomizers. Yet, using the correct means, it can be done. Remember that a random pad can be generated from any piece of random data. In fact, you could even grab random data by fetching cloud movements from satellite images. On a more "regular" level, there are hardware random number generators and other things. Check the update in my answer.

Comment: @e-sushi - So where this fails then would be that it needs to be able to be generated programmatically for my requirements.  We are looking to determine if it would be possible to create a completely secure and easy to use method inside the base programming language.  So relying on a satellite or specific technology that could fail would not be acceptable.  It would need to be able to be generated though computer logic entirely.

Comment: @Chad : Reading about "missing reliability" in relation to my "satellite images" example, I think you misunderstood my reply. It was only an example where to get random data from.

Comment: @Chad : By the way... you actually seem to mean "software logic" instead of "computer logic". As (like I've indicated before) there are "reliable hardware solutions" to fit your needs. Those fit your "computer logic" definition perfectly and offer more than enough of the "reliability" you are expecting. They provide the random data generator you're looking for and most solutions also offer other cryptographic functionality. One of many examples: http://www-03.ibm.com/security/cryptocards/

Comment: @Chad : and a few more of them (to prevent people from thinking I prefer IBM solutions)... https://www.fox-it.com/en/fox-it-solutions/state-secret/security-modules/fox-randomcard , http://www.dcbnet.com/datasheet/sseds.html?gclid=CNC1hNHR5K0CFUWDDgodTzZmLA , http://www.protego.se/ or https://www55.ssldomain.com/comscire/Merchant2/merchant.mvc?Screen=PROD&Store_Code=C&Product_Code=QW0001&Category_Code=QWPRODUCTS ; and when you check any search-engine for "hardware random number generator" you'll ample of other  options. Software solutions will not be able to reach the same quality and security.

Comment: @e-sushi - "Software solutions will not be able to reach the same quality and security." That is my belief too.  Though I was hoping someone with a more knowledge in the field would be able to do a better job of communicating why exactly that is.

Comment: One commonly known software mechanism for generating key in software: In Linux /dev/random attempts to provide information theoretic security i.e. quality of OTP.  Just read the same amount of information from /dev/random than is your data to be secured. It may take a while though. BTW, most things that are considered Vernam cipher are not secure. RC4 is one comment way of generating key stream. If key stream generation is used, the result is stream cipher, not OTP. Thus RC4, for instance, is not OTP.

Comment: If a processor or microcontroller has a hardware random number generator built in, and some particular instruction or sequence of instructions will use it to generate a random number, I would regard a piece of software for such a controller as a "computer program which generates random numbers".  Such a program would not be able to run on all computers, but that wouldn't mean it wasn't "a program".

Comment: @MSalters: While even an xor-based OTP(x) won't give an attacker no information about the content of a message, it will allow an attacker who intercepts a message and guesses it's contents the ability to replace it with a message of the attacker's choosing.  A secure scheme should ensure that even an attacker who knows the plaintext and ciphertext should not be able to infer anything useful about the key used to send the text.  Sending otp(f(otp(x)) with separate pads for the two OTP functions would seem like a big improvement even if f(x) was pretty simple.